# Why did sDNA prepare report an error

Tags: arcgis-10.2, sdna

I used sDNA Prepare to repair the road network in ArcGIS10.2, but the error was always reported. Could you tell me the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is this line:

"Nonetype object has no attribute PartCount"

It looks like your input data contains null geometries. Try running the ArcGIS "Repair Geometry" tool on it, then run again.

(In future by the way - no need to screen grab error messages - it's much better to copy the text :) )